# Is ThreadLocal correct for my use-case?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

This is how our functional code is structured.
Functional code calls `ConfigAdapter` which can fetch the configurations from any other store.
Now with the change in the requirements and to decouple the configurations, we created a new class called `ABCConfigAdapter` (Consider "ABC" to be some business specific term).

`ABCConfigAdapter` has same methods as `ConfigAdapter` but now has one more extra parameter to be passed called `ABCConfigAttributes`. `ABCConfigAttributes` determines the way in which we fetch the configuration for "ABC" business use-case.

Since `ConfigAdapter` was used where ever the functional code requires some configuration, now the changes are huge. That is not the actual problem, the problem here is how to pass `ABCConfigAttributes` as the object for `ABCConfigAdapter`?

Here are some of the ways of doing it:

1. Since the data in `ABCConfigAttributes` is specific to a particular thread, we thought of storing `ABCConfigAttributes` in `ThreadLocal` and where-ever we want to call `ABCConfigAdapter` we fetch `ABCConfigAttributes` from ThreadLocal and pass it on to `ABCConfigAdapter`
2. Make changes to pass `ABCConfigAttributes` from the top class to the hierarchy everywhere!

Obviously #2 is more costly because it has lot of intrusive changes. I want to understand whether is it a good practice to store Business objects in ThreadLocal (as described in #1) in these type of use-cases?

Comment: ThreadLocal guarantees for every thread a new version. Even `static` seems better. I would go for some persistancy like XML-Preferences or serialization.

Comment: `ThreadLocal` is aimed to manage a special variable which has _a different value_ for each thread. Then, ask yourself: If your program has a different `ABCConfigAdapter` for each thread, and there are no `ABCConfigAdapter`s shared between threads, then ThreadLocal is a safe solution.

Comment: Apologies there was a typo in #1 (instead of mentioning ABCConfigAttributes I mentioned ABCConfigAdapter), corrected it! please check now!